# Album art for music files in jwplayer

Tags: html, jwplayer

In JW player is there any way we can add the album art for music file.

Below is code snippet i am using in jwplayer in HTML 5 page.

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
                playlist: playerdata,
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                fallback: 'false'
              });
```

Comment: What is the option for playerdata? The image would go in there.